# C# - Remove certain files from DirectoryInfo

Tags: c#, file, foreach, listbox, directory

I have been searching for about an hour now and just can't manage to find a solution to my problem. I'm trying to display all .txt files in a certain direcetory besides the ones ending with "_days.txt". Here's my code, hope you can help. Thanks!

```
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    if (file.Name.Substring(file.Length - 9, file.Length) != "_days.txt") //I get errors on this row, saying "Arg1, Arg2; Cannot convert from "long" to "int"
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `file.Name.EndsWith`?

Comment: @wgraham why not make that an answer and get some rep?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your initial question (and to answer why you are getting the error), you are trying to use a result of an operation against `long File.Length` (which is another issue as this is the size of the file, not the length of the file name) as a parameter to `string.Substring(int, int)`. Since an operation between `long` and `int` will return a `long` (as it is the larger type), you would need to convert it to an `int` first -- but `File.Length` isn't the field you want anyway.

Try using [String.EndsWith(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith.aspx), as it's more readable anyway.

```
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    if (!file.Name.EndsWith("_days.txt")) 
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple clean, LINQ solution using `Where` to filter the list we iterate over.

```
foreach (FileInfo f in files.Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("_days.txt") == false))
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(file.Name); 
}
```

The where is basically replacing your if statement. Each object you iterate over will have the condition in the Where statement applied to it.